# Cannot see einstein analytics dashboard in einstein bot performance tab

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein-analytics-dashboards, einstein-bots, chatbot

I have download einstein bot by value package from app exchange and created a dashboard in Analytics studio but i cannot see the analytics dashboard in einstein bot performance tab.
[image]